# How do I avoid this recursive function call?

Tags: java, function, recursion, compiler-errors

So getArea calls getHeight which calls getArea and creates a never ending loop.
I'm being graded on writing as little code as possible and reusing as many functions as possible.

Is there anyway I could get this working with the function calls rather then just substituting the forumula for getArea into getHeight where getArea is called?

```
//returns the area of a trapezoid
public double getArea(){
    double height = getHeight();
    double area = (.5 * ((getPoint(3).getX() - getPoint(4).getX()) + (getPoint(2).getX() - getPoint(1).getX()))) * height;
    return area;
}

//returns the height of a trapezoid
public double getHeight(){
    double area = getArea();
    double height = (2 * area) / (((getPoint(3).getX() - getPoint(4).getX()) + (getPoint(2).getX() - getPoint(1).getX())));
    return height;
}
```

Comment: Have one of the functions take the height / area as input, or just use the sin/cos builtins to do some basic trig (since you know the base and top height)

Comment: I have to use the function headers provided which were public double getHeight() and public double getArea(), so I can't make one function take the other as a parameter.
I'm willing to substitute the formula into the function to avoid the recursion but even then I'm still at a lost because each function relies on the other.
Any help on how I would do this?

Comment: I believe you're confusing the principle of recursion with simply calling one method from within another? Just use trig in the case of not being able to take extra Params.

Comment: I'll write you a full answer in a moment.

Comment: Please do I'm at a complete loss.
Reason I thought it was a recursion issue is because the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
Is recursion when a function calls itself? So that wouldn't apply for two functions calling on each other infinitely? Whoops. Still new to the programming grammar.

Comment: Yeah you've got it. This is a circular call (two call each other); there's also recursive (method calls itself); infinite recursive (recursive calls never terminate).

Comment: This is a case of *mutual recursion*, which in itself would not be bad, but here there is no way it can ever terminate. You'll have to use the full formula for either of the two, e.g., in height, and use height in the formula for area.

Comment: How did it go? @Basic

Comment: Went good. Thank you for the advise. Helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For review:

1. Circular

   ```
   void a() {
       b();
   }
   void b() {
       a();
   }
   ```
2. Recursive

   ```
   bool binarySearch(int* list, int searchFor, int size) {     
       if (size == 1 && list[0] != searchFor)
           return false;

       int split = size / 2;

       if (list[split] == searchFor) {
           return true;
       } else if (list[split] > searchFor) {
           binarySearch(list, searchFor, split);
       } else {
           binarySearch(list[split], searchFor, split);
       }
   ```
3. Recursive infinite/non-terminating

   ```
   void a() {
       a();
   }
   ```

---

On with the "answer":

[image]

So I'd need more information to give you the simplest answer but here is at least one options; reliant on you having x *and* y coordinates (anyone else can feel free to add).

**Use points to find height:**

You seem to be able to call .x() to get the x-values so if the y-values are present just find the height by taking the difference of each of the point pairs (A&D, D&C, C&B and B&A).

For each of these, you will have a vector *m* `(m.x, m.y) = (a.x, a.y) - (b.x, b.y)` which you can find the magnitude of `magnitude = sqrt(m.x * m.x + m.y * m.y)`.

Now you have all four side lengths you can compute the height from that like so (a&b are top and bottom, c&d are sides):
[image]

Comment: Y-values would only work if you have common Ys within the points.  If the trapezoid is rotated to not be parallel to an axis then that wouldn't work.  There seem to be a lot of unanswered pieces here.  Are the points in a given guaranteed order or do you have to figure out what they are?  At a minimum you need to figure out the length of the lines between the points I would think